# Trying to click on an Input element

Tags: java, html, selenium, input, webdriver

I am trying to click on the Choose Files button which is inside a SPAN and Input Tag.

I tried using Xpath, Id and Name and I am unable to click.

```
<span>
Choose 
<u>f</u>
iles...
</span>
<input id="inpFileUpload" multiple="" size="50" name="inpFileUpload" title="File (required)" onkeydown="return allow_all_keys(event);" onkeypress="return allow_all_keys(event);" type="file"/>
</span>
```

Comment: I see 1 span that is closed before the input and then nothing opened before the input with a close span after the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am little late to answer, But You can also use the `id` and `name` to locate it

Using id:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("inpFileUpload")).click();
```

Using name:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("inpFileUpload")).click();
```

Comment: @johnsonambrose Please check my answer too

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to click the Input Element, you can try:

1. `cssSelector` :

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#inpFileUpload")).click();
   ```
2. `xpath` :

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='inpFileUpload']")).click();
   ```